# Casting music and video from the same iOS application with different background option doesn't work

Tags: swift, google-cast, google-cast-sdk

I have an iOS application that can play music and video. You can cast music or video from the app using the chromecast sdk. I've been reading the documentation about playing in background. When setting this code:

```
let criteria = GCKDiscoveryCriteria(applicationID: chromeCastReceiverAppID)
let options = GCKCastOptions(discoveryCriteria: criteria)
options.physicalVolumeButtonsWillControlDeviceVolume = true
options.suspendSessionsWhenBackgrounded = false
GCKCastContext.setSharedInstanceWith(options)
```

I can keep controlling my music while casting and the app is in background this is great. When casting a video the session is lost while in background and when the app resume it doesn't resume automatically as stated in the documentation. it does work if I set the suspendSessionsWhenBackgrounded = true but then I get suspended when casting music and can't switch to the next song.

Is there a way to switch that option based on what type of content I'm casting?